# .find() based on logical OR of two attributers

Tags: jquery

I'm filtering a contact list using `name` and `lastname` set as attributes on a `div`

```
<div class="user" name="Sheldon" lastname="Cooper">...</div>
```

At the moment I'm able to do a partial search on a single attribute.
(filter is the content of an input text)

```
ContactsList.find(".user .name:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().hide();
ContactsList.find(".user .name:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
```

How I do on both? And how can I filter those that don't contain the filter value in both attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ContactsList.find(".user")
 .parent().hide()  // hide all parents of .user elements
 .end()  // revert collection back to .user elements
 .filter("[name*=" + filter + "], [lastname*=" + filter + "]")  // filter the collection based on attribute values
 .parent().slideDown(); // show the filtered elements
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r23yLfrn/2/

Comment: There's a way to make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem, you can try this:

You hide all

```
ContactsList.find('.user').parent().hide();
```

You show filtered results:

```
ContactsList.find('.user[name="'+ filter + '"], .user[lastname="'+ filter + '"]').parent().slideDown();
```

Comment: I was wondering if selectors can be concatenated : `('.user[name="'+ filter + '"][lastname="'+ filter + '"]')` - Don't leave a space after `.user` because the selector will look for children, not `.user` itself

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe for not in both

`ContactsList.find(".user:not([name*=" + filter + "]):not([lastname*=" + filter + "])").parent().hide();`

For OR you can do this

`ContactsList.find(".user[name*=" + filter + "], .user[lastname*=" + filter + "])").parent().hide();`

Also notice the [`*`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) which is selects those that `contain` the string

Answer (score 1):

You must have created a custom `:` expression because jQuery core would not filter an attribute using `attribute:Contains()` the way your code is shown.

Should also use `data-` attributes and take advantage of jQuery `data()` method to read them

I would suggest using `filter(function)`. It gives you far more flexibility than selectors do

HTML

```
<div class="user" data-name="Sheldon" data-lastname="Cooper">...</div>
```

JS

```
$('.user[name]').filter(function(){
    var term = filter.toLowerCase(),
        data = $(this).data()
        name = data.name.toLowerCase(),
        lastName = $data.lastname.toLowerCase()
    return name.indexOf(term)>-1 || lastName.indexOf(term)>-1
})
```